# Get ExecStartPre to work with iptables and ipset

Tags: iptables, centos7, systemd

I have a rule in iptables that calls a black list I created with ipset. My rule is

```
-A INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -m comment --comment "BLACKLISTED TRAFFIC" -j DROP
```

On reboot it's not persistent. This causes iptables not to start on boot as there is no black list. The command that I use to generate the list is

```
/usr/sbin/ipset restore < /etc/ipset-blacklist/ip-blacklist.restore
```

In order to get iptables to start I set up /usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service like this

```
[Unit]
Description=IPv4 firewall with iptables
Before=ip6tables.service
After=syslog.target
AssertPathExists=/etc/sysconfig/iptables

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/ipset restore < /etc/ipset-blacklist/ip-blacklist.restore
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start
ExecReload=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init reload
ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init stop
Environment=BOOTUP=serial
Environment=CONSOLETYPE=serial
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

If I do a

```
 systemctl start iptables.service
```

I get back:

```
ipset[26566]: ipset v6.38: Unknown argument <
```

Now if I modify iptables.service to be like this

```
[Unit]
Description=IPv4 firewall with iptables
Before=ip6tables.service
After=syslog.target
AssertPathExists=/etc/sysconfig/iptables

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=ipset restore < /etc/ipset-blacklist/ip-blacklist.restore
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start
ExecReload=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init reload
ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init stop
Environment=BOOTUP=serial
Environment=CONSOLETYPE=serial
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Then I get an error of

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.21: Set blacklist doesn't exist
```

So it seems like ExecStartPre is not being ran. Any tips?

Comment: Some generic comments  : after modifying a unit file you need to run systemctl daemonreload and you may need to use the absolute path to the ipset command

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/ipset restore < /etc/ipset-blacklist/ip-blacklist.restore"
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: No need to say "thank you", accepting answer is better)